# Run react isomorphic on iis

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, isomorphic-javascript, iisnode

I'm trying to get react running using node.js with [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) on iis

I've installed the latest node and the latest iisnode and used this stackoverflow as a guide but can't get past error 500. [How to run Node.JS server for a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434755/how-to-run-node-js-server-for-a-web-application)

any guides on how to do this on iis?

Comment: Could you put a sample app along with the iisnode configuration somewhere on github? It may very well be an environmental issue, but looking at the code may be worth a try.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for but, an alternative to this is to use a reverse proxy in IIS

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier could you show me how this would work

Answer (score 0):

This not a direct answer but rather an alternative. You could use IIS' reverse proxy plugin and just reverse proxy a VirtualServer or sub folder on a virtual server to your NodeJS server.

If you need multiple processes, you could use [Node's built-in clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Here are two ways to proceed :

1. [Easyest way IMO](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis)
2. [Easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947595/iis-reverse-proxy-to-node-js)